# Uncaught ReferenceError: mozRTCSessionDescription is not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, knockout.js, signalr, .net-4.6

I have an ASP.NET MVC app (.NET Framework 4.6.2) which has a front end on Knockout.js it also uses signalR.

The app was working fine until we upgraded Firefox to version 113.0 and 113.0.1. The app shows blank screen after login. It's working fine on previous version 112.x.x and below also working fine on latest chrome version.

Im seeing this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: mozRTCSessionDescription is not defined" on the console and this error doesn't show up on other browsers.

I have checked media.peerconnection.enabled is set to true in firefox.

I need assistance on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it was removed in that version, [see the release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/113.0beta/releasenotes/).

> Removed the long-deprecated mozRTCPeerConnection, mozRTCIceCandidate,
> and mozRTCSessionDescription types. Sites should utilize the
> non-prefixed variants instead.

Comment: Hi @iamdlm ! thanks and this did resolve partially as Im now able to login to my app but still unable to connect to softphone on firefox although it works fine on chrome. Along with mozRTCPeerConnection, mozRTCIceCandidate and mozRTCSessionDescription, I also change mozSrcObject to srcObject but still it wont work. This is the error I noticed logged on firefox but not on chrome.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request